# AzCopy Ignoring or recreating Checksum

Tags: c#, json, azure, md5, azcopy

I'm using the Azure tool AzCopy to export data from table storage, modify the exported data, and then import the data into another table storage table.  I'm using the following command to export:

```
AzCopy /Source:https://MYSERVER/MYTABLE/ /SourceKey:SOURCEKEY /Dest:C:\migration /Manifest:MYTABLE
```

Since you cannot add a filter for the export, I'm filtering the data post-export, remove data from the JSON as necessary.  I'm then using the following command to import this data to another server:

```
AzCopy/Source:C:\export /Dest:https://MYOTHERSERVER/MYTABLE /DestType:Table /DestKey:DESTKEY /Manifest:MYTABLE EntityOperation:InsertOrReplace
```

These operations work fine when I do not manipulate the JSON file.  When I do, however, the contents of the file are, of course, changed and the checksum in the manifest file no longer matches.  When I go to do the import, I get a "file is corrupt" message.

Here is what the manifest file looks like:

```
"Version":2,"PayloadFormat":"Json","Checksum":5500917691400439101,"AccountName":"SERVER","TableName":"MYTABLE","Timestamp":"2017-08-25T14:10:53.7489755Z","SplitSize":0,"TotalDataFiles":1}
```

How can I get AzCopy to either not validate the checksum or replace the checksum?

I've tried the following code to recreate the checksum, but when I do on the original JSON, it does not match:

```
var md5Hash = getFileHash(file);
var checksum = convertHash(md5Hash);

private byte[] getFileHash(string filePath)
{
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            return md5.ComputeHash(stream);
        }
    }
}

private string convertHash(byte[] data)
{
    var algorithm = MD5.Create();
    var result = BitConverter.ToUInt64(data,0);
    return result.ToString();
}
```

This returns `4500814390503865422`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AzCopy doesn't support skipping checksum validation during table import for now. BTW, the checksum recorded in manifest file is actually CRC rather than MD5, and it's calculated by aggregating CRC of all exported files rather than the single manifest file.

Comment: Given that's how the checksum is created, can it be recreated?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that there isn't an easy way to do so for now.

Comment: But if you only have one exported data file (that's exactly your case per the manifest file content shared by you), the new Crc64 checksum can be easily calculated by some hash tool (e.g. DP Hash https://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=1757). After that, you can replace the data file name and manifest file content with the new Crc64 checksum.

Comment: Thanks for telling me what type of checksum is used in the manifest file.  I have that working now.  What do I use to rename the data file?  Here is my sample file name: `TABLENAME_0_0_4C572F7EC695C53D.json`.  I assume I have to hash the file contents a certain way and replace the `4C572F7EC695C53D`.

Comment: Yes, you need to replace 4C572F7EC695C53D part.

Comment: I understand.  The question is with what?

Comment: With the new CRC64 checksum of your data file calculated by some hash tool (e.g. DP Hash https://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=1757)

Comment: There are two hashes needed.  One is the Crc64 hash of the data file.  This hash needs to replace the `checksum` value in the manifest file.  This value in my example is "5500917691400439101".  The second hash needs to replace the "4C572F7EC695C53D" string in the data file filename.  I'm unclear on how to generate this hash.

Comment: Please note that "5500917691400439101" is just the DEC representation of HEX value "4C572F7EC695C53D". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: crc64 parameters for jacksum tool, uses CRC-64-ECMA-182 polynomial, (and are also parameters for Rocksoft (tm) Model)

jacksum.bat -a crc:64,42F0E1EBA9EA3693,FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,false,false,FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF -X .\files

Comment: So, in conclusion, modify the data, calculate the CRC64 checksum, put that into the filename, convert to DEC and put that inside the manifest file. Thank you all, your answers were really helpful and I was able to upload modified data.

Comment: @podvlada Could you explain/link to the tool you used to calculate the checksum? Those steps didn't work for me, I'm not sure if I used different parameters when calculating the checksum (I just used some tool online that lets you upload files and gets the checksum)